# Swift on Linux - importing third-party modules

Tags: linux, swift, import

I am writing some entry-level swift code on Linux as a learning exercise.

As a general task, I wish to make use of a third-party Swift module in my own code. Let's call this module "Foo". The Foo module has a Package.swift file, and after running `swift build` in that directory, it has created `.build/debug/libFoo.so`.

Now I wish to do two things with this:

1. Be able to `import Foo` in the REPL.
2. Be able to import Foo in my own swift program, perhaps by linking with this shared object.

I have a feeling both tasks are related, so for now they are in the same question.

For 1., I don't understand how Packages become 'findable' by the REPL. I tried `swift -F .build/debug -framework Foo` but I get the "no such module" error. I also tried `swift -I .build/debug` with the same result.

For 2., I examined `swiftc --help` and there are `-L` and `-l` options however I was not able to find the right way to use these:

```
$ swiftc main.swift -L ../foo.git/.build/debug -llibFoo.so
main.swift:1:8: error: no such module 'Foo'
import Foo
       ^
```

I'm using both/either Swift 2.2 or 3.0 (used `swim` rather than `swift build` for 2.2 as there is no `swift build` - but it produces the same output I believe).

Note that I understand `swift build` can automagically download and build a third-party module however I'd like to know how to incorporate on-disk modules as they may be my own work-in-progress modules.

---

EDIT: I tried a little experiment with swift3 based on a discovery that you can use local paths as the `url:` parameter in the Package's `dependencies:` list, at least for local development.

I created a directory `Bar` and `Bar/Package.swift`:

```
import PackageDescription
let package = Package(name: "Bar")
```

I also created `Bar/Sources/bar.swift` containing:

```
public func bar(arg: Int) -> Int {
    return arg * 2
}
```

The intention is that module `Bar` provides the function called `bar(arg:)`.

I did a `git init`, `git add .`, `git commit -m "Initial commit."` and then `git tag 1.0.0` to create a tagged *local* git repo for this module.

Then back at the top level I created directory `Foo` and `Foo/Package.swift`:

```
import PackageDescription
let package = Package(
    name: "Foo",
    dependencies: [ .Package(url: "../Bar", majorVersion: 1) ]
)
```

Note the relative path for `../Bar`.

I also created `Foo/Sources/main.swift`:

```
import Bar
print(bar(arg: 11))
```

Now when I `swift build` inside `Foo`, it clones `Bar` and builds it. However then I get the following error; **no such module**:

```
$ swift build
Compile Swift Module 'Bar' (1 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Foo' (1 sources)
.../Foo/Sources/main.swift:1:8: error: no such module 'Bar'
import Bar
       ^
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): .../swift-3.0-PREVIEW-4-ubuntu14.04/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f .../Foo/.build/debug.yaml
```

Oddly, if I do the exact same build command again, I get a different error:

```
$ swift build
Compile Swift Module 'Foo' (1 sources)
Linking .build/debug/Bar
.../Foo/Sources/main.swift:3:7: error: use of unresolved identifier 'bar'
print(bar(arg: 11))
      ^~~
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): .../swift-3.0-PREVIEW-4-ubuntu14.04/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f .../Foo/.build/debug.yaml
```

I had hoped that this might work.

Comment: I could not reproduce the problems with your most recent attempt: I followed the steps you described and `Foo` successfully imported `Bar` and called the `bar` function.  Another question: how did you manage to build a module that produced a `libFoo.so` library?  When I built the `Bar` module from your latest example, there was no `libBar.so` in `.build/debug`

Comment: @OmniProg thanks for trying it out. I'm not sure why it worked for you. I will try with a different version of Swift. It is encouraging that it does work for you. On your second point, before I made the Foo/Bar example, I was working with a third-party module that wasn't called 'Bar' (it was called Swifter) and it did generate a libSwifter.so file, but I wanted to pose the question as a general one. I made the assumption that the .so was a standard output, but apparently it's not. I don't see anything in Swifter that might explain why it generated a .so either.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I'm using the exact same version, swift-3.0-PREVIEW-4-ubuntu14.04, so it may be worth just cleaning up all the derived files and re-trying from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

> Be able to import Foo in my own swift program, perhaps by linking with this shared object.

Using the example you posted in your question after "EDIT," this seems to work fine provided you use `swift build`. The [Swift Package Manager](https://swift.org/getting-started/#using-the-package-manager) will handle all of the dependencies for you, even if they're on-disk (this works on Swift 3 and 4):

```
$ cd Foo

$ swift build
Cloning /path/to/Bar
HEAD is now at 0c3fd6e Initial commit.
Resolved version: 1.0.0
Compile Swift Module 'Bar' (1 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Foo' (1 sources)
Linking ./.build/debug/Foo

$ .build/debug/Foo
22
```

Note that Foo/.build/debug doesn't contain any .so files:

```
$ ls Foo/.build/debug
Bar.build  Bar.swiftdoc  Bar.swiftmodule  Foo  Foo.build  Foo.swiftdoc  Foo.swiftmodule  ModuleCache
```

I believe the .swiftdoc and .swiftmodule files are used instead.

> Be able to import Foo in the REPL.

This part's a bit messier, but I found the solution [here](https://github.com/profburke/swiftreplmadness). To apply it to your example, you have two options:

- [Use `swift build` with extra flags](https://github.com/profburke/swiftreplmadness/tree/cdf55998c158576f62f4a7b021e7213e0d631012) (this works on Swift 3 and 4):

  ```
  $ cd Bar

  $ swift build -Xswiftc -emit-library
  Compile Swift Module 'Bar' (1 sources)

  $ swift -I .build/debug -L . -lBar
    1> import Bar
    2> bar(arg: 11) 
  $R0: Int = 22
    3>
  ```

  This creates libBar.so in the current directory:

  ```
  $ ls
  libBar.so  Package.swift  Sources
  ```
- [Update your Package.manifest](https://github.com/profburke/swiftreplmadness) (this is specific to Swift 4):

  1. The updated Package.manifest would look something like this:

     ```
     // swift-tools-version:4.0
     import PackageDescription

     let package = Package(
         name: "Bar",
         products: [
             .library(
                 name: "Bar",
                 type: .dynamic,
                 targets: ["Bar"]),
         ],
         targets: [
             .target(
                 name: "Bar",
                 dependencies: [],
                 path: "Sources"),
         ]
     )
     ```
  2. And this is how you do the build and call the REPL:

     ```
     $ cd Bar

     $ swift build
     Compile Swift Module 'Bar' (1 sources)
     Linking ./.build/x86_64-unknown-linux/debug/libBar.so

     $ swift -I .build/debug -L .build/debug -lBar
       1> import Bar 
       2> bar(arg: 11) 
     $R0: Int = 22
       3>
     ```

  This creates libBar.so in the .build/debug directory:

  ```
  $ ls .build/debug
  Bar.build  Bar.swiftdoc  Bar.swiftmodule  libBar.so  ModuleCache
  ```

If you're unable to reproduce these results, I would suggest cleaning out any .build directories and .so files, and installing a clean version of Swift (I recommend [swiftenv](https://swiftenv.fuller.li) for this).

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation, Swift on Linux with its Package Manager is work in progress, so no wonder there are bugs and lack of information.  However, here is what I found by experimenting and reading help.

If the module `Foo` has a library, `libFoo.so`, in `/LibLocation` and `Foo.swiftmodule` in `/ModuleLocation`, then it is possible to import and use `Foo` in a Swift program, call it `main.swift`, and then compile it by doing

```
swiftc -I /ModuleLocation -L /LibLocation -lFoo main.swift
```

One can also do it in REPL by launching it as

```
swift -I /ModuleLocation -L /LibLocation -lFoo
```

i.e. essentially giving it the same arguments as to `swiftc`.  BTW, if the module was built using `swift build`, the `ModuleLocation` is likely the same as `LibLocation`.

As I mentioned in an earlier comment, your example with `Foo` and `Bar`, both built using `swift build`, worked for me just fine, so I could not reproduce the problem.

BTW, in addition to reading swift.org documentation and command line help, one can glean plenty of interesting and potentially useful information by running `swift build` and other commands with the `-v` flag.  To find out about some hidden options available with `swiftc` do

```
swiftc -help-hidden
```